# jMeter: randomizing queries across an list of key values

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, jmeter, hana

I am using jMeter to conduct a series of database load tests. The database table contains several billion transactions for ~500k key values. I need to issue queries to retrieve all records for randomized key values. This would be easy if the key values were numeric and consecutive, as I could randomize across a numeric range of values (0 .. 500000) - however they are strings, so I need to extract a distinct list of key values first so that jMeter can pick random values to issue the queries. 
I can query the key values from the database, or place them in a CSV at the start of each test run.
This is a performance test, and the machine has lots of memory, so I would prefer if jMeter can load the key values into memory before beginning the test.

I dont know the best technique to use to configure jMeter to pick randomized values from a list - is there a technique to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [__StringFromFile](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function can help. It reads next string from input file (or even multiple files) each time being called. When end of file is reached the function starts over from the beginning. For extended information on using this and other JMeter's functions check [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series.